# v-if statement to compare one parameter and if matches return another parameter within the same object on Vue js

Tags: json, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

What would be an v-if that I could use to look for a matching title in an object on a json file and retrieve the object content if title is found.

Here is the sample json file I am using:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "image_path": "static/products/T130-SHEET-COLLECTION.jpg",
      "title": "Productivity Tools",
      "title_color": "badge-warning",
      "heading": "T130 Sheet Collection",
      "read_more_url": "javascript:void(0);",
      "content": "blanket posuere proin blandit accumsan senectus netus nullam curae, ornare laoreet adipiscing luctus mauris adipiscing pretium eget fermentum, tristique lobortis est ut metus lobortis tortor.",
      "vendor": "George Courey",
      "space": "Bedding",
      "category": "Linen"
    },
    {
      "image_path": "static/products/PRESTIGE-PLUS-T180-SHEET-COLLECTION.jpg",
      "title": "Productivity Tools",
      "title_color": "badge-warning",
      "heading": "Prestige Plus T180 Sheet Collection",
      "read_more_url": "javascript:void(0);",
      "content": "blanket posuere proin blandit accumsan senectus netus nullam curae, ornare laoreet adipiscing luctus mauris adipiscing pretium eget fermentum, tristique lobortis est ut metus lobortis tortor.",
      "vendor": "George Courey",
      "space": "Bedding",
      "category": "Linen"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`v-if` in `v-for`:

```
<div v-for="item of data">
    <div v-if="item.title === 'condition'">
        {{ item.title }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what your condition would be. ie. are you matching duplicates or to another value.

Either way, I would recommend that you use a `computed` instead of a relying on a `v-if`. This has numerous benefits, such as cleaner separation of template and logic, makes for easier reading an debugging, and easier to write the filtering logic in js.